# Where is "Android version to use when rendering layouts in the IDE" set in Android Studio?

Tags: android

Android Studio 2.1.2

Whenever I switch projects or start Android Studio from scratch the dropdown in the Layout Preview called "*Android version to use when rendering layouts in the IDE*" defaults to 24.   Since that is Android N it produces an error saying "***Rendering Problems***  Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later.  Install a supported JDK".

But I'm not using Android version 24.    I'm typically using 23 or 21 or 17, depending on my project.   So I set it to that.   But Android Studio doesn't "remember" it, so next time I open the project it's back to 24.

Where is the Android version used for rendering layout previews stored, so it will remember it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is: (don't mind the paint skills)

[image]

Simply change to API 23 here.

**EDIT**:

In order to keep it that way, go to **Tools > Android > SDK Manager** and un-tick the API 24, since you do not need it yet and it's only partially ready at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to desable the Automatically pick best where you select the android verson API. When this options is selected the Android Studio pick the last Android API version.

Comment: Where is that setting?

Comment: In privew tab, next to globe with an android icon.

Comment: In Android Studio 2.2 preview api 24 was fixed.

Comment: @user316117, In the answer by Vucko, the line he is pointing - "Automatically Pick Best", is "checked". Click on that line again to uncheck it. Then select whatever version you want from the same list. Now Android studio will remember it. Sorry did not look at the date, its too old thread.